# Strange Performance issues with where() vs find()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, mongodb, mongoid

Mongoid 3.1.6
Rails 3.2.21
MongoDB 2.4.9

We're seeing strange performance issues with `find()` vs `where().first`:

```
$ rails c
2.1.5 :001 > Benchmark.ms { User.find('5091e4beccbce30200000006') }
 => 7.95 
2.1.5 :002 > Benchmark.ms { User.find('5091e4beccbce30200000006') }
 => 0.27599999999999997 
2.1.5 :003 > Benchmark.ms { User.find('5091e4beccbce30200000006') }
 => 0.215 
2.1.5 :004 > exit

$ rails c
2.1.5 :001 > Benchmark.ms { User.where(id: '5091e4beccbce30200000006').first }
 => 7.779999999999999 
2.1.5 :002 > Benchmark.ms { User.where(id: '5091e4beccbce30200000006').first }
 => 4.84 
2.1.5 :003 > Benchmark.ms { User.where(id: '5091e4beccbce30200000006').first }
 => 5.297 
2.1.5 :004 > exit
```

These both appear to be firing off the same queries. Can someone explain why we're seeing such a huge difference in performance?

Configuration:

```
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      uri: <%= REDACTED %>
      options:
        consistency: :strong
        safe: true
        max_retries: 1
        retry_interval: 0
  options:
    identity_map_enabled: true
```

Comment: Do you have index on this field? Why are you saving mongoId as string (or this is the syntax of rail, which I am not familiar with)?

Comment: @SalvadorDali: `id` in Mongoid will be `_id` inside MongoDB. Mongoid will (usually) convert the string to an ObjectId for you.

Comment: what happend when you change identity_map_enabled to false? I think that .where doesn't use identity_map_enabled

Comment: @kuadrosx: The identity map is disabled by default in Mongoid 3 isn't it?

Comment: @mu is too short: maybe but  it is enabled in the posted configuration

Comment: @kuadrosx: Right, so it is. I think it is worth noting that I see similar results (or at least that `where(...).first` takes longer than `find`) with Mongoid 4 which doesn't have an identity map.

Comment: Yes, it appears that `find` leverages the identity map, while `where` does not.

Comment: @mu is too short: yes, I don't know why mongoid  short by :_id here is a discussion about this issue https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/3768

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `find` uses the identity map, while `where` does not. If I set `identity_map_enabled` to `false`, then the performance of `find` vs `where` is identical.

Moral of the story: use `find` instead of `where` when possible.

I've heard that the identity map is removed in Mongoid 4.x. So maybe this issue only affects folks on older versions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my assumption why the first one was few orders of magnitude slower (I am writing it from mongo point of view and have zero knowledge about ruby).

The first time you fired the query it was not in the working set and this caused slower performance. The consecutive times it was already there and thus performance is better. If you have small number of documents, I would find this behavior strange (because I would expect that all of them would be in a working set).

The second part with [$where](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) surprises me because I would expect all the numbers be bigger than with `find()` (it is not the case with the first event) because:

> The $where provides greater flexibility, but requires that the
>   database processes the JavaScript expression or function for each
>   document in the collection.

Comment: Mongoid's `where` doesn't (always) map to MongoDB's `$where` operator. The `where` method just builds a selector for MongoDB so `M.where(:a => 'b')` is like `db.ms.find({ a: 'b' })` inside MongoDB. The name is used to match the usual ActiveRecord/SQL name.

Comment: @muistooshort thanks for both of your explanations. I can not understand this part: `where doesn't (always) map`. How can it be? I my opinion it either maps to $where or not. Also most probably my answer does not really make sense in ruby word, so I am inclined to remove it.

Comment: I mean that `where` can use the `$where` operator if you say `M.where(:$where => '...')` but it won't use `$where` unless you explicitly do it. Yeah, not exactly my clearest use of English ever.